# How can I add custom fields to checkout in Magento Go?

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento-go

I want to add a textarea element to the checkout page for comments, etc. I have found articles and extensions for doing this in Magento CE but nothing for Magento Go. **Is this possible and if so, how?** Thanks.

Comment: Done, we looked into it for the managed hosting. Extensibility requires CE or EE which eliminated GO from our consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot do it through the various control panels that Magento Go provides, then it isn't possible.

In order to eliminate customer fiddle breakage, Go is put in a straight jacket.